# What is a pair of nonces?

Tags: mining-theory, nonce

From https://www.sps.ed.ac.uk/sites/default/files/pictures/ekja03/Mining25.pdf page 10:

> The bitcoin system is therefore designed to ensure that it takes around ten minutes on average before any miner anywhere manages to discover a nonce, or pair of nonces, that generates a hash with enough zeros. /…/

What is a pair of nonces and how does a pair of nonces solve a block?

Answer (score 2):

> **What is a pair of nonces [...]**

I guess they refer to [nonce](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonce) and [extranonce](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=extranonce).

> **[...] and how does a pair of nonces solve a block?**

Talk of "solving" a block doesn't make much sense. They just mean that miners find values for the data in a block that result in the hash of the block being a number no bigger than the current network target number. Those values include nonce, extranonce and others.

Comment: (I meant solving in the mathematical sense, as any mining task can be seen as solving an equation, defined by the `CNTN`, the list of transactions in a block, etc.)